# Android: sharing multiple content types

Tags: android, android-intent, sharing

I want to share audio files. I have a server where I can upload my files. I want to share either the audio files itself (with Dropbox for example) or upload the file to my server and share only the link to it (via e-mail). When I create the chooser, I want all the apps to show up, which can share audio, text or both. And I want to send the audio file only via the apps, that can share only audio. How can I do this?